# How to rewrite this function using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write shorter code using jquery. What is the best way to rewrite this function in jquery.

```
function searchDone(results) {
    var result = null;
    var parent = document.getElementById('resultList');
    parent.innerHTML = '';
    var child = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < results.SearchResponse.Image.Results.length; i++) {
        result = results.SearchResponse.Image.Results[i];
        child = document.createElement('li');
        child.className = "resultlistitem";

        child.innerHTML = '<a href="' + result.MediaUrl +'"><img src="' +
            result.Thumbnail.Url +'" alt="' + result.Title +'" /></a>';

        parent.appendChild(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the data look like that you're getting back?  Is it XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bad idea to continually append to the same element in the DOM in loop. It means that the DOM will get redrawn every single time you append a new element.

Do something like this to append only once:

```
function searchDone(results) {
 var list = [];
    $.each(results.SearchResponse.Image.Results, function(i, v) {
        list.push('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' + v.MediaUrl +'"><img src="' + v.Thumbnail.Url +'" alt="' + v.Title +'" /></a></li>');
    });
 $('#resultList').empty().append(list.join(''));
}
```

This creates an array will all the "children" in it.  Once the each as looped over all the results it empties out the `#resultList` and appends all the children.

Comment: @Petersen +1 but you have to use the second argument - the first one is the index...

Comment: yes @PetersenDidIt, your code still doesn't work. Needs some tweaking

Comment: @alex oops looks like there was an extra `)` hanging out after `function(i, v)` should work now.

Comment: That works, Thanks for the efforts. @aSeptik has a similar answer with the exception that he forgot to empty before appending. Your answer is the winner.

Answer (score 1):

```
function searchDone(results) {
    var result = null;
    var item = '';
    $('#resultList').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < results.SearchResponse.Image.Results.length; i++) {
        result = results.SearchResponse.Image.Results[i];
        item = '<li>' +
                 '<a href="' + result.MediaUrl + '"> ' +
                   '<img src="' + result.Thumbnail.Url + '" alt="' + result.Title + '"/>' + 
                 '</a>' +
               '</li>';
        $('#resultList').append(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! ... I'd also use the 'each' method in place of the for loop

Comment: @Jared You have to declare the local variables

Comment: @Sime: Can you explain what you mean, and the reason why?

Comment: @Jared You have two undeclared variables: `result` and `item`. If you don't declare them, they become implicit global variables which is something that you certainly don't want.

Comment: @amir75: I left that the way it was since it wasn't really related to jQuery. If I were to rewrite that part, I might use do/while instead. I don't think it ALL has to be jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
function searchDone(results) {
    var r,
        p = $('#resultList').empty(),
        arr = results.SearchResponse.Image.Results;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        r = arr[i];
        p.append('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' + r.MediaUrl + '"><img src="' + r.Thumbnail.Url + '" alt="' + r.Title + '" /></a><li>');
    }   
}
```

---

As @Petersen already pointed out, DOM manipulation should be avoided inside loops. The alternative code below will create the HTML source code string via the loop, and the append the whole string at once.

```
function searchDone(results) {
    var r,
        p = $('#resultList').empty(),
        arr = results.SearchResponse.Image.Results,
        s = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        r = arr[i];
        s += '<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' + r.MediaUrl + '"><img src="' + r.Thumbnail.Url + '" alt="' + r.Title + '" /></a><li>';
    }

    p.append(s);
}
```

Comment: This will mean that you force the DOM to redraw every single time it loops, if this is a large list then the browser will freeze up while it loops and appends

Comment: short and clean @sime vidas. But @eseptic made better using of jquery. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you dont care about effects in the sense of "display one message one by one" you can display it all together... like this

```
function searchDone(results) {
    var lis = [];
    $.each(results.SearchResponse.Image.Results, function(i,item){
    lis.push('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' + item.MediaUrl +'"><img src="' +
            item.Thumbnail.Url +'" alt="' + item.Title +'" /></a></li>');
    }); $('#resultList').html( lis.join('') );
}
```

otherwise with a little bit of code you can have a nice fadeOut effect like this:

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/odimi4

```
function searchDone(results) {
    $.each(results.SearchResponse.Image.Results, function(i,item) ) {
        $('<li class="resultlistitem">').html('<a href="' + item.MediaUrl +'">'+
          '<img src="' +item.Thumbnail.Url +'" alt="' + item.Title +'" /></a>')
          .appendTo('#resultList').delay(i+'000').fadeOut(200,function(){$(this).remove()});
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You are querying for the `'#resultList'` element in each loop iteration. I'd be better if that element was cached.

Comment: Also, the first argument of the $.each callback is the index, not the value (which is the second parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your results are JSON

```
    function searchDone(results) {
     $("#resultList").empty();
     html = "";

//creating this as a string and appending at the end is faster than appending each element 'live' - depends how many search results you have
    $.each( results.SearchResponse.Image.Results, function(key,result){
      html +='<li><a href="' + result.MediaUrl +'"><img src="' +
                result.Thumbnail.Url +'" alt="' + result.Title +'" /></a></li>';
     });
     $("#resultList").append(html);
    }
```

Comment: your function(result) should be function(i, result).